# Gridview Autosort by column on button click or bind c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

Have an interesting issue that I'd love some thoughts on.  I have a Gridview that displays jobs under a certain work center.  Gridview works great everything like we want but after data is saved we want it to bind and reorder by a SQ #.  Seems easy enough however column 1 is a value from SQL the rest of the columns are from AS400 so can't just do a order by since they are two different servers and two different databases so tried doing this:

```
summGridView.Sort(summGridView.Columns[1], SortDirection.Ascending);
```

Which would work in a windows form however I'm doing this in a web form. Says can't convert from datafield to a string so tried adding ToString() and that gives the error of:

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Below is the screenshot of what I have I'd like it after I save data to order by SQ #.. thoughts?

[image]

Comment: You need to sort the source data before binding it to the GridView. Directly in SQL, sorting a DataTable or use Linq to OrderBy a List.

Comment: Can you take a Gridview and in LINQ do a sort on that?

Comment: No, it has to be the source data.

Comment: Hmm.  I don't add that SQ # field until I do a foreach row in gridview so I can get that SQ# from SQL using the order # and Oper Seq from AS400... so that wouldn't work.

Comment: @VDWWD I am redoing how I do my statment before I used a foreach on my gridview changing that to a foreach on my datatable row... before I was able to use this row.Cells[2].Text to get data from that row... however I try row.ItemArray[2].ToString() to get data from that row and it won't work.  do you know how to do that?

Comment: Here is a good tutorial https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/663532/How-to-Perform-Sorting-in-Gridview-in-ASP-NET

Answer (score 0):

I originally was doing a foreach in the Gridview to get the SQL value.  After talking with a co worker we decided to try pulling everything into a datatable foreach then doing dt.DefaultView.Sort = "SQ #" which then sorts everything then we pushed it to the gridview.  Works great now.